# What English translations are there of work done by the Italian school of algebraic geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, birational-geometry, translation

What English translations are there of work done by the Italian school of algebraic geometry?

Perhaps I'm being too spoiled here, given that mathematical French, German, Italian are much easier to pick up on the fly than say, mathematical Russian or Japanese, for a native English speaker.

Comment: Not quite what you're asking for, but Dolgachev's book [Classical Algebraic Geometry: a modern view](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/CAG.pdf) will keep one occupied for a while. He translates work of the classical algebraic geometers into English but also into modern mathematical language (which is really the more significant obstacle).

Comment: @dfk79 I would prefer original sources, although the bibliography for Dolgachev's book looks like a good start.

Comment: For about 15 years, Miles Reid's website mentioned a long-term project to translate Enriques' book Le Superficie Algebriche into English, with some Italian collaborators. This item has now disappeared from his list of projects, but I am fairly certain that some rudimentary translation of some parts of the book does exist. Perhaps a direct approach might yield something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [complete bibliography](http://math.unipa.it/~brig/sds/prima%20pagina/tirocinio/bibliografie.htm). It includes translations, but not in English (many in French, German, and Spanish).

From this bibliography I notice that only [Guido Fubini](http://math.unipa.it/~brig/sds/prima%20pagina/tirocinio/Fubini%20Guido%20biblio.htm) and [Beniamino Segre](http://math.unipa.it/~brig/sds/prima%20pagina/tirocinio/Segre%20Beniamino%20biblio.htm) occasionally published in English. [The collected papers of Giacomo Albanese](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Collected-Giacomo-Albanese-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0889117373), which I have not accessed, may well contain English translations.

In answer to the OP, assuming this bibliography is indeed complete, and with the possible exception of Albanese,$^\ast$ I would conclude that, no, there are no published English translations of original papers from the Italian school of algebraic geometry.

---

**$^\ast$ update:** I located the [table of contents](http://bvbr.bib-bvb.de:8991/exlibris/aleph/a22_1/apache_media/IRS233RYDV3AREGQ8VM3SEEB6YMQUK.pdf) of Albanese's collected papers, and it has only the Italian originals, no translations.

Comment: I am confused. OP is asking for English translations and your answer seem to be giving papers written in English.. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Praphulia Koushik Usually a translation into French is satisfactory, so this list is actually quite good.

Comment: @HarryGindi Satisfactory for who? "I'm being too spoiled here, given that mathematical French, German, Italian are much easier to pick up on the fly.." means that French is of same difficulty as that of Italian for OP... That list may be good but I am not sure if that answers this question...

Comment: @HarryGindi I am not wishing to start a debate... :) Thank you :) I have nothing to say on this..

Comment: The true problem that I see with this answer is that it lists a lot of works that are not about algebraic geometry.

Comment: @HarryGindi I suspect  that if you know enough French to read EGA or similar, you're not going to have big problems with mathematical Italian